# Passing vector to a function

Tags: c++

I have the following in my `main()`:

```
vector<Person*> alist;
add(alist);
printDetail(alist);
```

Then, in another file, I call it `function.cpp`, in this file, I have the following methods:

```
void add(vector<Person*> &mylist)
{  
    Person temp_p("firstname1","lastname1",20);

    mylist.push_back(new Person("firstname2","lastname2",20));
    mylist.push_back(&temp_p);

    printDetail(mylist);
}

void printDetail(vector<Person*> mylist)
{
    for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++)
    {
        mylist[i]->display();
    }
}
```

When I run this program, the `printDetail(mylist)`, inside the `add()` method, will print out both result without any problem, but in the `main()`, only the `firstname2` one will be printed out.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
mylist.push_back(&temp_p);
```

you are storing a pointer to a local variable in the vector. When the function returns, the object it points to ceases to exist, so your vector is left with a dangling pointer. This leads to *undefined behviour*.

Comment: can you please show me what I'm supposed to write in this line? I tried to pass the temp_p with different way, *, & etc..but all get error.

Comment: @Qin you cannot pass the address of `temp_p` to the vector in any way because `temp_p` is local to the function. You have to figure out another way of doing whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Qin you might be better off not storing pointers but `Person` objects in the vector. This makes the code both cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 1):

In the main function are trying to refer to an object that is deleted when the add() function returns. 
The other object is working fine because when you use the "new" operator, you explicit allocate memory for that object and it's not resolved automatically after the function finishes. 
Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you should allocate memory for the temp_p on your own (using the new operator) or create it as a global object.